# PHPUnit "Could not read phpunit.xml" on Travis CI

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I am encountering a strange issue while trying to run PHP unit tests on Travis CI.

**.travis.yml**

```
sudo: false
language: php
php:
  - 5.4

env:
  - VUFIND_HOME=$PWD VUFIND_LOCAL_DIR=$PWD/local

before_script:
  - pear install pear/PHP_CodeSniffer
  - pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
  - pear install phing/phing
  - composer global require fabpot/php-cs-fixer
  - export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
  - phpenv rehash

script:
  - phpunit --stderr --configuration module/VuFind/tests/phpunit.xml
  - phpunit --stderr --configuration module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml
  - phpcs --standard=PEAR --ignore=*/config/*,*/tests/* --extensions=php $PWD/module
  - phing php-cs-fixer-dryrun
```

module/VuFind/tests/phpunit.xml is a third party framework

module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml is our own code

**module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="sbvfrd">
            <directory>.</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

The tests from the third party framework run without errors. Our own tests do not work and we get the error message:

```
$ phpunit --stderr --configuration module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml
Could not read "module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml".
```

Locally (Mac OS X) all the tests run through. Strangely enough the Bootstrap.php defined in module/Swissbib/tests/phpunit.xml runs completely through on Travis CI, I verified this using echo statements. Nevertheless phpunit tells us that it could not read phpunit.xml.

Travis: https://travis-ci.org/swissbib/vufind

Repo: https://github.com/swissbib/vufind (development branch)

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution by downloading the phpunit source and debugging with it.

We were changing the directory within the Bootstrap.php file to a different location then the phpunit command was run from. We run the phpunit command from our project root folder and then changed the working directory to the tests folder, because we were using relative paths. I changed everything to absolute paths (using `__DIR__`) so we do not have to change the working directory anymore.

**Bottom line**: Do not change the directory in the bootstrap file as it causes phpunit to fail with this error message: Could not read phpunit.xml.

Comment: Using chdir in bootstrap.php was the case in my situation too, thanks for the solution!